# How to fetch all rows from objection.js

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I am using Knex.js & Objection.js, I want to display country drop down so I need all rows but it was only returning me 10 rows. How do I override the pagination functionality?

Is there any params I can set in url localhost:3031/countires?pages='All', there should be some easy way. I am using "knex": "^0.21.1", "objection": "^1.6.11" version.
default.js contain

```
"paginate": {
    "default": 10,
    "max": 2000
  },
```

For time being I just made the following changes in src\serivices\countries\countires.services.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const options = {
    Model: createModel(app),
    //paginate: app.get("paginate"),
    paginate: {
      default: 0,
      max: 0,
    },
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use("/countries", new Countries(options, app));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution need to add application or service before get hook in my case I added to /src/app.hooks.js

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    find: [
      (hook) => {
        if (hook.params.query && hook.params.query.$paginate) {
          hook.params.paginate =
            hook.params.query.$paginate === "false" ||
            hook.params.query.$paginate === false;
          delete hook.params.query.$paginate;
        }
        return hook;
      },
    ],
 }
}
```

How to call it from Postman :

```
GET http://localhost:3031/institutes?$paginate=false // all rows
GET http://localhost:3031/institutes //Using pagination
```

Nuxt.js

```
async mounted() {
    this.countries = await this.$api.countries.find({ $paginate: false });
},
```

vue.js

```
this.countries = await this.$axios.get('http://localhost:3031/countries?$paginate=false');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I could see your objection query for this route it would be helpful. But you could most likely set a value in paginate like this:

```js
paginate = {
  isPage: false,
  default:10,
  max:2000
}
```

Then in your query you can have an if statement to check if the isPage value is true or false. And only limit your responses if you have that value set to true.
Something like this:

```js
const countries = paginate.isPage
  ? await Country.query()
    .limit(paginate.default)
  : await Country.query()
```

If you need more help just reply to me and I'll respond as son as I can!

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply I think explain you the problem in incorrect way let explain you. 01 Countries list where I want to use pagination need to use default 02 In user creation I want to show drop down list box there I want to display all the countries. Now In this situation  I have only one get() to override How do I send parameters to limit or no limit result ?

Comment: I think my answer covers this scenario, by adding an additional field to your paginate object, you can check if you are trying to paginate or not. You could include a param in your url as well that could set the value to true or false, that way you can use the same get route, but have two different queries for it depending on if isPage is true or false. Once again if i could see the code for the query it would be a lot more helpful.